# Formula field with an hyperlink on the email template

Tags: email-template

I have a formula field called Search_Quote__c on VM_Sales_Order__c object. The field formula is as follows.

```
HYPERLINK("_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?str="&Quote_No__c, Quote_No__c)
```

WHen I try to put this field on email template it shows up like a big link

```
<a href="_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?str=Q-62867" target="_blank">Q-62867</a>
```

and not like a output link. Is there a way I can just show the quote number and not this big link.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the formula field as it will output as the fill link. Simply do this (HTML, custom Template, or VF):

```
<a href="_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults?str={!Quote__c.QuoteNumber}" target="_blank">{!Quote__c.QuoteNumber}</a>
```

Ensuring you use your correct merge fields. Since the formula field is using values from the object your email merge text just replicates the formula.

Comment: Hi Eric, Can you please elaborate what you meant. Mine is a visualforce email template not HTML template.

Comment: You can do the same thing in a VF email template. Just use the `<a>` tag in your VF template. Essentially recreate the formula output using html tags and merge fields on the vf email template do not use the formula field.